# whether to use numpy's dot or matmul function

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, numpy-ndarray

I need to do the following two operations:

- solve `Ax=b` by inverting the `n-by-n matrix A`, and
- solve `r=Ar` using power iteration (*i.e. by repeated multiplying current vector r by A*) such as one would do for the `PageRank` algorithm.

**My question is:** When computing the matrix-vector product `A^{-1}b`  or the matrix-vector product `Ar`, is it better to use `numpy.dot` or `numpy.matmul`?  (I understand there might be differences in higher dimensions, but my question is only for the case where `A` is a 2D array and `b`, `r` are vectors.)

Comment: For 2 and 1d it doesn't matter.  They do  the same.  One has a operator  version, and some added `ufunc` bells-n-whistles, the other a method version (and shorter name).

Answer (score 3):

From the [numpy doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) for `np.dot`:

> *Dot product of two arrays. Specifically, If both a and b are 2-D arrays, it is matrix multiplication, but using matmul or a @ b is
> preferred.*

So basically for your case, it does not matter, although `matmul` is preferred according to the doc.

Also since one of your arrays is 1-D, from [docs for `np.matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy.matmul):

> *If the second argument is 1-D, it is promoted to a matrix by appending
> a 1 to its dimensions. After matrix multiplication the appended 1 is
> removed.*

And:

> *matmul differs from dot in two important ways:
> Multiplication by scalars is not allowed, use * instead. Stacks of matrices are
> broadcast together as if the matrices were elements, respecting the
> signature*

Therefore, they would work the same in your case, but I would go with numpy doc's recommendation on using `matmul`.

Comment: The docs seem to leave it rather unexplained why `matmul` is preferred